# openstack nova-compute how to load multiple config

Tags: openstack, ceph

I want to configure mutilple ceph backends on one hypervisor in nova-compute.
In this document：

[OpenStack Nova: configure multiple Ceph backends on one hypervisor](http://ceph.com/planet/openstack-nova-configure-multiple-ceph-backends-on-one-hypervisor/)

but i can't start nova-compute service with two config file correctly. It only load the last config file rather than the two config file.

what is the way to load the multiple config file? thanks for help

Comment: How are you starting nova-compute ? Provide some example commands.

Comment: # systemctl restart openstack-nova-compute，just load the last config file

Comment: After you start nova-compute with systemctl, can you do

   ps aux | grep nova-compute

To see the command line options ? How many --config-file do you see ?

Comment: only the one  --config-file with the lasted config file

Comment: You should open a bug against your Linux distribution. Probably the systemctl start stop script is broken.